# Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' while executing program to read properties file

Tags: java, spring

I am simply trying to read one properties file through my code using spring with xml. Here is the code of my spring.xml file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
    <bean class="Test" id="t">
        <property name="p">
            <util:properties location="classpath:driver.properties"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am getting this error while execution.

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 152; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Your `schemaLocation` is wrong. It should always be `<namespace> <location>`currently you only provide namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your `xsi:schemaLocation` is not correct, try this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

P.S. `xsi:schemaLocation` in each line has two values, separated by a space. The first value is the namespace to use. The second value is the location of the XML schema to use for that namespace. There were no location in your `schemaLocation` and parser think that ...util is a location for ...beans. And not founds "beans" in schema: "Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'"

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation in each line has two values, separated by a space. The first value is the namespace to use. The second value is the location of the XML schema to use for that namespace. There were no location in your schemaLocation and parser think that ...util is a location for ...beans. And not founds "beans" in schema: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'